# how to check server is running in javascript?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm new the Phone Gap , I'm building an app where i need to check whether the server is running or not.

Here is my code

```
function config() {
    navigator.notification.prompt(
                                  '',  // message
                                  onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
                                  'Enter The Server IP',            // title
                                  ['OK'],
                                  '192.168.1.108'// buttonLabels
                                  );


function onPrompt(results) {
   if (!(/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(results.input1)))
   {
        navigator.notification.alert("Plz enter the correct Ip Address");
    }
    else
    {
        var temp = results.input1;
        $.ajax({
               url:temp,
               type: "HEAD",
               timeout:1000,
               statusCode: {
               200: function (response) {
               navigator.notification.alert("connected successfully");
               navigator.notification.alert("Ip address is saved for your mobile");
               localStorage.setItem("ipAddress",results.input1);
               window.location.href="login.html";
               },
               400: function (response) {
               navigator.notification.alert("Please Check whether Server is Running??");
               },
               0: function (response) {
               navigator.notification.alert("Please Check whether Server is Running??");                   }
               }
               });



    }
}
```

when i'm running this code with correct IP Address still i'm getting only 0 response alert message.

Comment: Which server are you talking about?

Comment: my local server i'm using apache tom server ,when i enter  ip address of  system where the server is running , it has to check for whether that system server is running on that machine

Comment: That information should be in your original message. Are you aware that Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). So this function appears to have no purpose.  FWIW: you are placing your comma incorrectly.

Comment: have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Best of Luck.